# Is the glucose produced from photosynthesis considered an aqueous solution when written as a chemical reaction?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, photosynthesis

In the *very simplified* reaction for photosynthesis, the states of the reactants and products are clear to me except for glucose. Inside a plant, it would be dissolved in water, so would it be an aqueous solution or be considered a precipitate in some way? In the reaction

$$\ce{6CO_2 {_{(g)}} + 6H_2O{_{(l)}} \rightarrow C_6H_{12}O_6{_{(?)}} + 6O_2{_{(g)}}}$$

what would I put in the place of the question mark?

Comment: Yes, immediately after synthesis, glucose is dissolved in water. However, it is later used by the plant to build more complex sugars as well as starches and celluloses, which are not necessarily water-soluble.

Comment: I’m curious as to why you ask this question — what you will do with this equation when completed. You do realize that what you have written is not ‘a reaction” but a partial summary of a whole series of reactions, which, in addition, involve other substrates that you have not included.